# C# Create a bill message box with items that were checked displayed

Tags: c#, checkbox, messagebox

There's a form with three checkboxes and a button. Upon clicking on the button a messagebox is suppose to show up and  display all the items that were checked on the form with price before tax and total. The price before tax and total are taken care of, but how would I display what was checked by the user on that form in the message box that will serve as a bill.

```
if (checkCheeseSnackBread.Checked == true)
        {
            price += 10;
            items += "Cheese Snack Bread - $10";
        }
        else
        {
            price -= 10;
        }
```

Just need some guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by "what was checked by the user on that form in the message box that will serve as a bill."

Comment: Add `"\r\n"` to each of the strings when you add them to the `items` string. That will give a new line in the message box.

Comment: Three checkboxes and a button. You check nothing and click the button a message box will appear and say that no items were checked. If you check 1st and 3rd item, for example, then after clicking the button the message box will appear and say that user have selected 1st and 3rd item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I must say that the code you've written seems to hold a logical eror. If the checkbox isn't checked then you shouldn't do anything. In your code you subtract the item-price from the total price. This way you give a discount of 10. If they don't buy it, don't add it. That's all.

So, now you know what they've bought, you can use a StringBuilder to populate the message.
Quick and dirty:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("Ticket")
builder.AppendLine();

if (checkCheeseSnackBread.Checked) // == true is not needed
  {             
      price += 10;             
      items += "Cheese Snack Bread - $10";     
      builder.AppendLine(Cheese Snack Bread - $10);    
  }        

// Do the same for other checkboxes
// Add the totals    
Messagebox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

There is an other way: loop through the controls on the form, if it's a checkbox ==> add the text to the StringBuilder.  This way it doesn't matter how much checkboxes there are. You just have to make sure that the text-property is used to print on the ticket (messagebox).

Comment: But since the item population happens during CheckedChanged event, if I keep checking and uncheking one of the items and click the button the messagebox will display that same item as many times as I've checked it over and over.

Comment: In your case you just need to put this code in the button_Click event and see if the checkboxes are checked. This way you only need to look once instead of every time someone changes the checkbox.

Comment: Whoah I realized that logical mistake I made. Damn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display a string you generate.

Check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx